# Split with irregular pattern (regex) SCALA

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, split, rdd

I have a textFile data that looks like

```
28.225.37.170 - - [14/May/2019:00:00:05 +0000] "GET xxxxxx "-" "yyyyyy"
80.156.48.65 - - [14/May/2019:00:00:10 +0000] "GET xxxxxxx "-" "yyyyyy"
....
```

I want to get a RDD looking like this

```
(28.225.37.170 ,  14/May/2019:00:00:05 +0000 , xxxxxx , yyyyyy ) 
(80.156.48.65 ,  14/May/2019:00:00:10  +0000 ,  xxxxxx , yyyyyy )
```

I want to know what's the regex that I can use to do the splitting of my data

```
val reg: scala.util.matching.Regex = """?????""".r  // ????? any suggestions ?
rdd.map( lines => lines.split(reg) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pattern match on a regex? If your lines present a define number of elements to extract and different separators, I could be better:

```
val l1 = """28.225.37.170 - - [14/May/2019:00:00:05 +0000] "GET xxxxxx "-" "yyyyyy""""
val l2 = """80.156.48.65 - - [14/May/2019:00:00:10 +0000] "GET xxxxxxx "-" "yyyyyy""""

val reg = """(.*) - - \[(.*)\] "GET (.*) "-" "(.*)"""".r

def splitMyLine(line:String) = line match { case reg(a,b,c,d) => "line: \n" +Seq(a,b,c,d).map(s => s" __ data: $s").mkString("\n") }

Seq(l1, l2).foreach(l => println(splitMyLine(l)))
```

gives:

```
line: 
 __ data: 28.225.37.170
 __ data: 14/May/2019:00:00:05 +0000
 __ data: xxxxxx
 __ data: yyyyyy
line: 
 __ data: 80.156.48.65
 __ data: 14/May/2019:00:00:10 +0000
 __ data: xxxxxxx
 __ data: yyyyyy
```

You can simply define your splitting function like this then:

```
def splitMyLine(line:String): Seq[String] = line match {
    case reg(a,b,c,d) => Seq(a,b,c,d)
}
```

Hope it helps.